# Can I split chapters with CSS?

Tags: epub, creation, css, editing, indesign

I'm learning to create epubs with InDesign. If you want a particular element inside a chapter (e.g. a subheading) to appear at the top of the next page, you can assign it a CSS style that has been designated for that purpose.

However, the CSS is really just a gimmick; the file is literally split, with the text you want to appear at the top of the next page beginning the new file.

I have separate files for each of my chapters. But imagine a chapter that has several subheadings that are supposed to appear at the top of different pages. I don't want to create a separate file for each subheading.

So is there a CSS style that will remove an element from the normal flow and force it to appear at the top of the next page, so I don't have to literally split my file into separate files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be accomplished with the `page-break-after` ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)) or `page-break-before` ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp)) CSS properties. Pretty obviously, these create a page break after or before the element that they are applied on.

---

Here are a couple of examples of their use:

**page-break-after**

*CSS style*

```
.newpage {
    page-break-after:always;
}
```

*HTML code*

```
<p class="newpage">This text is on a page. The text will be split after this paragraph.</p>

<p>This text is on the following page, after the split.</p>
```

**page-break-before**

*CSS style*

```
.newpage {
    page-break-before;
}
```

*HTML code*

```
<p>This text is on a page. The text will be split after this paragraph.</p>

<p class="newpage">This text is on the following page, after the split.</p>
```

---

As you can see, they accomplish the same thing with a small difference (where you should put the property itself); depending on the situation, one could be more appropriate than the other.

I tested it with Calibre internal reader and on a Kobo Glo device, and it works in both of them.

Comment: I changed page-break-after to page-break-before and it does exactly what I wanted. ;)

Comment: On second glance, I see that your solution is fine as is; I guess there are two different ways of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Yes, they both do the same thing, the only difference is where you should put the styling. Anyway, I've expanded my answer to include also a page-break-before example.

Comment: Another tip: I just learned about a second rule "for future devices." I don't know any details, but here it is: new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
    break-before: always; /* for future devices */
}